# How to add Images to xcode so they don't disappear when deleted/moved from computer.

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I create my images to use in my xcode project and save these to my desktop.  I then drag the images from the desktop into an images folder I created in xcode.  If I build/run the project everything works great.  However if I move the images from my desktop somewhere else, xcode can no longer "find" the images and acts as though they no longer exist (their filenames go red).  How can I copy images into my project so that are actually IN the project itself and not dependent on my Mac's fie location? (after all, once you deploy an App obviously the Mac won't be there to supply the images so they need to be in the actual project.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a resource into Xcode there is a little checkbox which says `Copy items into destination group's folder`. Ensure that is checked

[image].

Comment: Perfect that was it!  Thank you for the screenshot as well!!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project in Xcode, Xcode creates a folder for the project. If you put your images in that folder instead of your desktop, then when you later add them to your project they will be added using a relative path and will always follow your project's folder wherever you move it.